# No such module with cocoapods swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am having problem with importing frameworks using cocoapods. My pod file looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'AppDemo' do
    pod 'AKPickerView-Swift'
    pod 'PickerView'
    pod 'Scale'
end
```

I am using Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7+

Comment: Once you've run 'pod install', you need to close your project and open the .xcworkspace file, not the .xcodeproj

Comment: Refer to [Using CocoaPods > Installation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#installation).

Comment: Sometimes a clean helps, try going to Project > Clean, or while holding the option key do Project > Clean.

Answer (score 2):

Close your Project and open the new `YourProject.workspace` that was created after you run `pod install` in your projects root directory in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after creating new schema in xcode. Goto Xcode -> Product -> Schema. I still don't understand why problem appeared initially. I faced this problem in .xworkspace. Cleaned project couple of times but it didn't help.